# How do I debug using a Google Home device in Beta testing?

Tags: actions-on-google

I have a Google account associated with user@mydomain.com and that is what my Google Home device is setup with. I have a Google Action in Beta that has passed Review and have added that email as a Beta Tester. From the opt-in link I click "Send to device > Device Name (Home Mini)" and nothing happens. When I say "Hey Google, talk to " on that device, then I get "Sorry, I don't know how to help with that yet."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send it to the phone first and activate it through a device with the Google Home app installed first. Once you've done that, it should be available on all your devices linked to that account.